# Large scene render

Tags: rendering, scene

Right now I'm creating a large scene with a big amount of geometry. I want to use it in a project, but need only some parts of it at one time, I don't need to render it all.

The question: are there some features to tell blender to load only PARTS of the mesh that are in view of the camera now? Because scene is going to be at least 40k polygons + characters like 12k poly each, so it's pretty heavy to render.

And I heard that during Sintel movie development was used something like a technology that cuts off all mesh parts that are out of camera view during render. Is it true?

Answer (score 2):

If your scene consists of separate objects you can use render layers to separately render them and then afterward compine them. 
https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/how-to-render-a-complex-scene-without-crashing

Comment: Yes, I know about layers. But layers are not suitable for any situation (some objects can be intersected with a few layers) and it's not very comfortable.